# LWC - getObjectInfo not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, getobjectinfo

I am trying to get all the record type options for Opportunity. I am using getObjectInfo directly copied from the documentation but I keep getting the same error:

Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';


export default class New_Opportunity extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track objectInfo;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    get recordTypeOptions() {
        console.log('options ', this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('recordId: ', this.recordId);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.objectInfo));
    }
}
```

[image]

I am really unsure why this is not working as I have directly copied the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is wrong in several places. First, the variable is declared twice, which is a bad practice. Second, the data property will be undefined the first time your getter is called. Third, `connectedCallback` will be called before the wire completes, so `this.objectInfo` would not have any data in it. Fourth, the name of the component would cause the file to be named `new_Opportunity` and accessed as `c-new_-opportunity`, which would be annoying and not "normal" compared to how names should look. Fifth, the getter doesn't return a value. This makes it useless and technically incorrect.

It should look like this:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';


export default class NewOpportunity extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    get recordTypeOptions() {
      if(this.objectInfo.data) {
        console.log('recordTypeInfos', 
          JSON.stringify(
            this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos
          )
        );
        return this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
      } else {
        return {}; // An empty mapping for now...
      }
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('recordId: ', this.recordId);
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. I've sent a message to the Salesforce Documentation to have this corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much! @sfdcfox

Comment: @someguy You're welcome!